# ember.js - call base action from overriden action

Tags: ember.js

I want to call a base action from an overriden action like in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ugEGAPI/3/edit).

I know if I return true then it will propagate to the action, the problem is that I want the action to execute and then do something in the overriden action.  Is this possible?

Comment: you're not overriding the 'doSomething' from 'App.ApplicationRoute'. your 'App.IndexRoute' does not extends from 'App.ApplicationRoute'. That pattern would work if you were extending from it, but that's not the case.

Comment: I mean, the way routes work in Ember, is that if you have one action with the same name as the one in 'App.ApplicationRoute', it will be overwritten, but that's not what we know as overriding methods when you inherit from another object.

Answer (score -1):

As @fanta noted you aren't exactly *overriding* the action because you'd have to extend from your parent route, but aside from that:

If you return `true` from the action handler the action will bubble up to any parent routes. Simple as that you can specify to call the parent's route action handler or just let the action die in your handler

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions:{
    doSomething: function(){
        //do things
        if (something) {
            //I got this, no need for my parent
            return true;
        } else if (otherThing) {
            //I can't do this, let my parent route handle it
            return false;
        }
        return defaultOption;
    }
  }
});
```

I can't think of a scenario in which using action bubbling you couldn't (implicitly) call your parent's route action handler. Do you?

**EDIT** 
If you were to wait for a promise in the `remove` method of the object you want to remove you can use something like this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions:{
    removeConfirmed: function(){
      // do some handling
      console.log("I may transitionTo");
      self.transitionToRoute('otherRoute', 'someParam');
    }
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  actions:{
    remove: function(){
      var self = this;
      this.get('content').remove().then(function() {
        // you could transition from the controller
        self.transitionToRoute('otherRoute', 'someParam');
        // or if you need some handling in the route
        self.send('removeConfirmed');
      });
      // you could let the action remove action bubble up
      return true;
    }
  }

});
```

If there's no need to wait for a promise then I don't see why returning true and letting the action bubble wouldn't work, since the action in the route would be called.
The important thing to note is that the controller can send actions to itself. If they are not handled by controller itself the action will bubble up to its route and any subsequent parent routes

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I mentioned in the question that propagation will not work in my instance.

Comment: What's your scenario?

Comment: The action in question is a delete.  I want to call the delete action in the base action and then transition to a different route.